# What adhesive/glue is best to join PVC pipe to MDF?

Tags: wood, glue, pvc

I'm running a piece of 90mm diameter PVC pipe through a sheet of 20mm thick MDF. I've cut a hole the right diamater in the wood to fit the pipe through, and I'm wondering what the best glue would be to join the pipe in place.

I've been using liquid nails for the rest of the project but I'm not sure how well it will bond to the PVC. Should I use this, two part epoxy or something else?

It needs to be as strong as possible since the joint will be under a fair load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two part epoxy works well (maybe JB weld), just rough up the pvc a bit and clean it first. How much of a load are you talking about? If it is substantial, you may have to attach the PVC mechanically to the MDF.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that. It's for a cat climbing post, so the pipe will stand vertically joined into the base which is MDF. Do you think I need brackets or something as well, or will the surface area inside the 20mm MDF be enough to make the bond pretty strong? The pipe is maybe half a metre tall.

Comment: Also, do I want a rigid or flexible epoxy?

Comment: For that kind of load you probably don't need anything stronger than the liquid nails if your joint is tight enough.(I'm assuming roughly 4in (100mm) pipe)